# RabbitMQ: Consume item after the previous one is finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

I'm new to RabbitMQ. What I want is to execute only one item at a time, the next one will be consumed after the previous one is finished.

Here is how Consumer is created:

```
consumer.assertQueue(queue, { durable: true });
consumer.consume(queue, handleMessage, { noAck: false });
```

Here is function handleMessage:

```
async function handleMessage(message) {    
    console.log('handleMessage', message.content.toString());
    // wait for 1 second
    await wait(1000); 
    console.log('ACK', message.content.toString());
    consumer.ack(message);
}
```

The Publisher will send items like this:

```
publisher.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from('1'));
publisher.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from('2'));
```

Here is the log. It seem does not wait for the handle process to wait 1 second to finished:

```
handleMessage 1
handleMessage 2
ACK 1
ACK 2
```

What I want is:

```
handleMessage 1
ACK 1
handleMessage 2
ACK 2
```

Mean message 1 must be finished before it handle message 2. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need **blocking** `wait` rather than an async one...

Comment: Hi @WiktorZychla, can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single queue with a single consumer, you can set the prefetch to 1.

```
channel.prefetch(1)
```

You can get more detail from RabbitMQ 's official doc:

> The value defines the max number of unacknowledged deliveries that are permitted on a channel. Once the number reaches the configured count, RabbitMQ will stop delivering more messages on the channel unless at least one of the outstanding ones is acknowledged

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is still not working

Comment: @DũngNguyễn Could you explain more detail to update your question?

Comment: Oh, I did figure it out. I should put `consumer.prefetch(1);` before the `consumer.consume(...)`. It's working now. Thanks a lot